# Binary search tree Recursively return to root

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I need to create a method in java that recursively determines the distance from any given node back to the root. The method returns an integer that shows how many nodes away the specific node is from the root. The node class is given below

```
Public class Node
{
int data;
node left;
node right;
}
```

No global variables or attributes allowed, and I cannot modify the node class. I've looked it up and each solution tells me to modify the node class to include a node pointer for a parent node. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Just find the path to this node from the root counting number of steps.

Comment: **Great**, Now comeback here when you actually have any problem !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `parent` stored in each node, search would require O(log N) operations (in case of balanced tree)--you just walk through parents and count steps until `parent == null` which means root node.

But without `parent` field, you need to recursively traverse the whole tree starting from the root, looking for a given node. It requires O(N) operations:

```
/** Returns the distance between "n" and "current" plus "step" 
/*  or -1 if "n" not found                                     */
int distance(Node n, Node current, int step) {
    int res = -1;
    if (n == current)  // node found
       return step;                     
    if (current.left == null && current.right == null)  // leaf node
       return -1;
    if (current.left != null)   // search in left subtree
       res = distance(n, current.left, step + 1);
    if (res > 0) 
       return res;
    if (current.right != null)  // search in right subtree
       res = distance(n, current.right, step + 1);
    return res;
}

//....
Node root;
Node given;
int dist = distance(given, root, 0);  // distance between "root" and "given"
```